# On asymptotic complexity class notation?

Tags: asymptotics, notation

Is the class of problems with complexity $O(n^{n^\epsilon})$ at every $\epsilon>0$ same as class of problems with complexity $O(n^{f(n)})$ at every $f(n)\in\omega(1)$ and hence both classes are equivalent to $\mathsf P$ ($n$ is number of input bits)?

(This is my view. Denote $C(n^{n^\epsilon})$ to be class of problems solvable in $O(n^{n^\epsilon})$ at every $\epsilon>0$ and let $D(n^{f(n)})$ be class of problems solvable in $O(n^{f(n)})$ at every $f(n)$ in $\omega(1)$. Does $\cap_{f(n)\in\omega(1)}D(n^{f(n)})=\cap_{\epsilon>0}C(n^{n^\epsilon})$ hold?  $\forall n\in\Bbb N\wedge\forall\delta>0 \exists\epsilon>0:n^\epsilon<1+\delta$ and so $C(n^{n^\epsilon})$ is smaller than $D(n^{f(n)})$ at every $f(n)$ in $\omega(1)$. However for every $\epsilon>0$ there is an $f(n)\in\omega(1)$ such that $f(n)<n^\epsilon$ at large enough $n\in\Bbb N$ and so $D(n^{f(n)})$ at any $f(n)$ in $\omega(1)$ is smaller than $C(n^{n^\epsilon})$. We then conclude both $O(n^{n^\epsilon})$ and $O(n^{f(n)})$ at any $f(n)\in\omega(1)$ are morally equal. Since $O(n^{f(n)})$ at any $f(n)\in\omega(1)$ is same as $\mathsf P$ we have the notation.).

Comment: Have you tried [using the standard methods](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/824/sorting-functions-by-asymptotic-growth)? Where does that lead you?

Comment: @Raphael this is not a query of computation. It is a query of notation.

Comment: I don't think so. You are forming a hypothesis about two Landau classes, namely that one is included in the other -- that something you prove, not denote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The time hierarchy theorem shows that there are problems which can be solved in time $O(n^{\log n})$ but not in time $O(n^{\log\log n})$. These problems can be solved in time $O(n^{n^\epsilon})$ for any $\epsilon > 0$, but not in polynomial time.

Comment: So I am wrong? $\cap_{f(n)\in\omega(1)}D(n^{f(n)})\subsetneq\cap_{\epsilon>0}C(n^{n^\epsilon})$ is correct?

Comment: I don't know, you tell me.

Comment: both classes seem same to me and equal to $\mathsf P$. But as you say $C(n^{n^\epsilon})$ does not seem to be $\mathsf{P}$. Hence my query.

Comment: Have you read my answer?

Comment: @YuvalFilms yes. updated my comment.

Comment: I am not fixing $\epsilon>0$ when I say $\cap_{\epsilon>0}$.

Comment: It all boils down to the fact that there are unbounded functions which are $O(n^\epsilon)$ for all $\epsilon > 0$, for example $\log n$.

Comment: So $\cap_{f(n)\in\omega(1)}D(n^{f(n)})\subsetneq C(n^{\log n})\subsetneq C(n^{n^{\epsilon}})$ is the correct way to interpret? ok.

Comment: is there a more strict natural formulation that would equal link a function of $n$ and $\epsilon$ with $f(n)\in\omega(1)$ (as described)?

Comment: That's a separate question.

Comment: @yucalfilmus I do not know how to frame the problem properly and so I posted as a comment.

Comment: Nevertheless, this is a new question, and you should ask it as such. That's how this platform works. If you find it hard to frame it, do your best.